# How did the Joker plan the heist so that no one knows he was there?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-dark-knight

In The Dark Knight, the opening bank robbery involves the Joker and a few thieves. When the jeep pulls up to pick up the Joker, he then puts on his mask and gets into the backseat.

Did the two thieves sitting in front not recognize the Joker? If not, this means the Joker planned the heist without actually being seen or known by the other thieves, how?

My guess:

- He got someone else to plan the job as the "Joker", and told the thieves driving the car to pick up another thief(the real Joker) waiting for them on the corner.
- They also, probably didn't know each other very well, and most likely met a few days before the bank heist, as they were easily able to kill each other for a "bigger slice". I would assume if they did know each other well, they would be hesitant to kill a friend.

Based on the conversation in the jeep, they mock the Joker for "sitting it out, and taking a slice", which indicates they aren't aware the Joker is with them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Did the two thieves sitting in front not recognize the Joker?

They might not have recognized him. They possibly didn't see his face when he gets in the jeep.

When we see the Joker in the beginning, he was facing the other side and that jeep came from behind.

[image]

Now, before getting into the jeep, he puts on his mask and he does so hastily before opening the door.

[image]

As we can see, it is possible that they didn't see his face and only knew that there is a guy to pick from this place, who has a mask in the hand and is a part of the plan but not the Joker. This can be confirmed from the conversation below.

Another possibility is, as you anticipated, they didn't know him. It seems that none of them didn't know who was the Joker. **It is easily possible that the Joker met them as the guy who told them the plan as told by some other guy who is the Joker.**

From the conversation between two guys in the jeep,

> **Man 1:** Three of a kind. Let's do this.
>
> **Man 2:** **That's it. Three guys?**
>
> **Man 1:** **Two guys on the roof. Every guy gets a share. Five shares is a plenty.**
>
> **Man 2:** **Six shares. Don't forget the guy who planned the job.**
>
> **Man 1:** He think he can sit it out and still take a slice. I know why they call him the Joker.

Later, after the money has been taken out from the vault, this conversation takes place.

> **Man:** If this Joker guy was so smart, he'd have had us bring a bigger car. (points gun). I am betting the Joker told you to kill me soon as we load the cash.
>
> **Joker:** No, no, no, I kill the bus driver.

So, from their conversation, it appears that no one knew and **the Joker came with the plan but he didn't let them know that he is the Joker, but he is a henchman.**

I am not sure how Bank manager knew this, but he says this when Joker kills all other guys and loads the final bag of cash in the bus.

> **Bank Manager:** You think you're smart, huh? The guy who hired youse, he will just do the same to you.

Comment: I think the bank manager meant in general, there is always another criminal waiting to steal from another one (they only think of themselves). He goes on to say that criminals in Gotham used to believe in honor. It could be that prior to Batman, the mob or a group of theives would never double cross each other and probably looked out for each other. With the arrival of Batman and Gordon, it probably become every man for themselves as they were being hunted and thrown in jail. Get close to someone and there is a good chance they might mention your named to the police if they were caught.

Comment: I think every man for himself was already there before batman, but there was still some kind of honor among them. Batman/Gordon didn't started it but I think joker introduced it into gotham

Comment: @Vishwa I am not sure what you're talking about.

Comment: Honor among thieves was already there, but arrival of joker made them act like every man for himself

Comment: @Vishwa - The Joker took advantage of the thieves greedy nature and told them to kill each other for a bigger slice, they are so blinded to it that they didn't question where or not it could happen to them. One of the thieves did figure it out, but he got hit by a bus. What I and I think the bank manager meant was before the Joker/Batman/Gordon that wasn't likely a possibility, they respected each other, with the introduction of Batman/Gordon and criminals being caught, it meant spending quite some time in jail unless you squeal, at that point, it's every man for themselves.

Comment: @Vishwa - There is no point in getting to know a fellow thief or even care about them, because they can turn on you in a second. That's what I meant, and the Joker probably knew this and took advantage. Given the conversation in the jeep, as I speculated they probably didn't know each other until a few days before the heist as they were easily able to kill each other. Think about it, would you kill a close friend for a bigger slice? If so, was he really your friend?

Comment: @Nexusfactor I agree some of your ideas, and answering your last question, **it depends... ;)**